# Task Creation and Email trigger using process builder

Tags: process-builder

[image]I need to create a task on 'XYZ' account and assign it to the account owner and also send an email to account owner on 1st of November every year.Task and Email have the same description.
I am trying to do this with process builder.
However this is not working.Am I doing something incorrect? I can't find an option to schedule on 1st of November every year. How to do it?
How to send an email to account owner using the same process builder?

Looking for some guidance.

Thanks
Deepa

Answer (score 0):

The best approach by now to execute tasks yearly on a given date is using the [Apex Scheduler](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/asynchronous_apex/async_apex_scheduled), you will have to do some coding though.

Starting on Winter 20, there is also a purely declarative solution for repetitive tasks: [Scheduled Flows](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter20/release-notes/rn_forcecom_flow_fbuilder_start.htm), but for now you can only set it to run on a daily or weekly basis. I guess you could try to work around this limitation by setting it to run daily and add a condition node like "is TODAY's month November and TODAY's day the 1st" -> Create Task and send Email.

Comment: Thanks. But I don't know coding as I am admin. Even new to flows. Is there any work around ?

Comment: Flows is the no-code solution for this use case so you may want to take a deeper look into that, you can use Trailhead to learn more about them. Then you can try and setup a flow for this and post any specific problems you may encounter once you try to produce a solution.

Comment: Hi,I am facing another issue.
Nothing is edited on the account. But to trigger a process some field should change on the 'XYZ' account record.But it is a random requirement that irrespective of some thing changes on that account, task should be assigned and email should be sent to the owner on yearly basis ( as a reminder to change few things).
So selecting 'Created or Edited' to start the process may not trigger the process as nothing is changed on this account.

Comment: Is there any work around?
Is there some thing in salesforce that will trigger email/create a task irrespective of some thing is edited or not on the account record? Not looking for APEx solution as I don't know coding.

Comment: As I mentioned, you should be looking into Flows (no code needed). It is a visual workflow builder, similar to Process Builder but you can schedule a flow to execute independently on a record change. You can learn more about flow builder in Trailhead e.g.(https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/flow-builder)